# How do i store data collected by "input" onto a text file in python

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python and i was just wondering if there is a way in which i could store data taken from the the function input for example:

```
    a = input("Question")
    b = input("Another Question")
    c = input("Another question")
    list = [a, b, c]
```

How can i store the list onto a text file?
Thank you

Comment: Do you want humans to read the data or a computer?  This will affect what the correct answer would be.

Comment: I want to store it in a text file for humans to read -- data collecting

Comment: What have **you tried**, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write each variable:

```
# Open a file
fo = open("filename.txt", "w")
fo.write(a);
fo.write(b);
fo.write(c);

# Close opend file
fo.close()
```

Or you can use a loop to write the list

```
for item in list:
  fo.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3 (guessing from your use of `input`), and after renaming `list` so it doesn't shadow the builtin name:

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in mylist:
        outfile.write(line + "\n")
```

will write the contents of `mylist` to the file `test.txt` in the current directory, each item on their own line.